# Webpack Peer Dependency Error in NPM When Webpack Is Installed

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting this error when running `webpack-dev-server` in npm:

```
webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

However, I already installed webpack. Here is my `package.json`. What am I missing?

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --progress --https"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: `webpack@^4.0.0` means Webpack v4, you appear to have installed v5. Have a play with e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have webpack@5 installed but the peer dependency warning is asking for webpack@4. There is [a bug filed in the `webpack-dev-server` issue tracker](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2807) about the incompatibility with webpack@5. As of a few days ago, they're working on it.

So one option is to be patient and watch that issue. When a version compatible webpack@5 is released, upgrade to it.

Another option is to downgrade your current project to webpack@4. I don't know how big the breaking changes between webpack@4 and webpack@5 are, but it's an option to try. Given that webpack@5.0.0 was released only a month ago, this may be an OK option. The latest version of webpack@4.x is webpack@4.44.2 and (as of this writing) is only 2 months old.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed a later version would be compatible. Downgraded to 4.43.0 and it fixed the issue.